# How to avoid iterrows for this pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need your recommendations to improve the following code.
The main aim of this is to calculate the time to start the machine based on the *MachineState* column. The actual code needs about 16–18 minutes to iterate through a dataframe of about 100 000 rows × 700 columns, which is too long for me.

```
ShutDownMask = df['MachineState'] == 'Shut Down'
ShutDownPos = np.flatnonzero(ShutDownMask)
# Create mask with Starting state, get index numbers/positions 
StartingMask = df['MachineState'] == 'Starting'
# Index list 
StartingPos = np.flatnonzero(StartingMask)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['MachineState'] == 'Shut Down':
        start = pd.to_datetime(row['Date'])
        try:
            idx = df.iloc[StartingPos].index[df.iloc[StartingPos].index.get_loc(start, method='backfill')]
            df.loc[index,'TimeToStart'] = idx - start
         except:
            print ('Something went wrong to find last index IDX') #For last set of record 
            pass
```

I have tried the recommended option with `np.where` but without success as I don’t know how to implement the counter to the next index.

```
df['TimeToStart'] = np.where(df['Machinetate'] == 'Shut Down',df.iloc[StartingPos].index[df.iloc[StartingPos].index.get_loc(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']), method='backfill')],pd.na)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

| Date | MachineState | TimeToStart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/02/2021 10:30:00 | Shut Down | 0 days 00:30:00 |
| 10/02/2021 10:40:00 | Shut Down | 0 days 00:20:00 |
| 10/02/2021 10:50:00 | Shut Down | 0 days 00:10:00 |
| 10/02/2021 11:00:00 | Starting |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following (`df` your dataframe):

```
def time_to_start(sdf):
    if sdf.MachineState.iat[-1] == "Starting":
        sdf["TimeToStart"] = sdf.Date.iat[-1] - sdf.Date
    else:
        sdf["TimeToStart"] = pd.NaT
    return sdf

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)  # Just to make sure
df = (
    df.groupby(
        df.MachineState.shift().eq("Starting").cumsum(),
        as_index=False,
        sort=False
      )
      .apply(time_to_start)
)
```

Result for

```
                  Date MachineState
0  10/02/2021 10:30:00    Shut Down
1  10/02/2021 10:40:00    Shut Down
2  10/02/2021 10:50:00    Shut Down
3  10/02/2021 11:00:00     Starting
4  10/02/2021 11:10:00    Shut Down
5  10/02/2021 11:30:00    Shut Down
6  10/02/2021 12:00:00     Starting
7  10/02/2021 12:40:00    Shut Down
```

is

```
                 Date MachineState      TimeToStart
0 2021-10-02 10:30:00    Shut Down  0 days 00:30:00
1 2021-10-02 10:40:00    Shut Down  0 days 00:20:00
2 2021-10-02 10:50:00    Shut Down  0 days 00:10:00
3 2021-10-02 11:00:00     Starting  0 days 00:00:00
4 2021-10-02 11:10:00    Shut Down  0 days 00:50:00
5 2021-10-02 11:30:00    Shut Down  0 days 00:30:00
6 2021-10-02 12:00:00     Starting  0 days 00:00:00
7 2021-10-02 12:40:00    Shut Down              NaT
```

Some explanations:

- One method to identify the blocks of rows that belong together is the following: First check in the `MachineState`-column if the row before contains `'Starting'` (-> `Grouping_1`) and then take the cumulative sum (`False`/`True` = `0`/`1`; -> `Grouping_2`):

  ```py
  df["Grouping_1"] = df.MachineState.shift().eq("Starting")
  df["Grouping_2"] = df.Grouping_1.cumsum()
  ```

  ```
                    Date MachineState  Grouping_1  Grouping_2
  0  10/02/2021 10:30:00    Shut Down       False           0
  1  10/02/2021 10:40:00    Shut Down       False           0
  2  10/02/2021 10:50:00    Shut Down       False           0
  3  10/02/2021 11:00:00     Starting       False           0
  4  10/02/2021 11:10:00    Shut Down        True           1
  5  10/02/2021 11:30:00    Shut Down       False           1
  6  10/02/2021 12:00:00     Starting       False           1
  7  10/02/2021 12:40:00    Shut Down        True           2
  ```
- Now use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) over this grouping to process the connected blocks of rows by [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).
- The `time_to_start` function used by `apply` does the following: It first checks if the sub-dataframe actually has a `'Starting'`-row. If that's the case, it takes the corresponding time and subtracts the `'Shut Down'`-times to build the `TimeToStart`-column. If that's not the case: Just indicate that by setting the `TimeToStart`-column to `NaT`.

---

Alternative approach which avoids `.apply`:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)  # Just to make sure
groups = df.MachineState.shift().eq("Starting").cumsum()
df["TimeToStart"] = df.Date.groupby(groups, sort=False).transform("last") - df.Date
if df.MachineState.iat[-1] != "Starting":
    df.loc[groups.eq(groups.iat[-1]), "TimeToStart"] = pd.NaT
```

Comment: Thank you Timus. Duration time decreased from 16-18minutes to 7sek! I need to figure out what you did to understand this approach :)

Comment: @Siwy Sorry, I hadn't given any explanations. I've just added some and hope they help.